# HTML/CSS/PHP display selected item on specific page

Tags: php, html, css

So basically, I have 8 items (these images are not stored on my database but on img folder) on my index page. When user clicks on a specific item, the whole image should be displayed on products_details.html . But I believe there's no control structure in markup language so I should do it with PHP. I really don't have an idea to achieve this thing.  Any ideas or suggestions to help me? I would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: [PHP Tutorial - Include file](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/include.php)

Comment: Can you explain more specific ?

Comment: Are `items` page & `product details` page separate?

Comment: @hallaji yes they are separate.

Comment: @Shafeeq basically I have two separate pages namely, index.html and products_details.html . On index.html, i have list of 8 images. When user clicks on a specific image, the full size of that image and details should be displayed on the products_details.html . And the same goes to other images. I don't want to create pages for each image to save time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added just a sample how to print selected item in separate page.

Items page (**HTML**): `index.html`

```
<a href="products_details.php?product_id=1"><img src="product1.jpg"></a>
<a href="products_details.php?product_id=2"><img src="product2.jpg"></a>
```

Products Details (**PHP**): `products_details.php` Change your file extension to write server side codes. `.php`

```
<!-- possible html codes here -->
<?php
if(isset($_GET['product_id'])){ // Retrieving product number
    // print product big image out:
    echo "<img src='product_big_{$_GET['product_id']}.jpg'>";
    // do more stuff to show details...
}
?>
<!-- possible html codes here -->
```

Read more on [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) about `HTTP GET variables`

**Update:**

When a user click on the link in `index.html` page, (e.g. second `a`) `product_id=2` variable passed to the products_details.php via the URL parameters. We retrieve it's value by this super global variable: `$_GET['product_id']` and automatically print out `product_big_2.jpg`

Comment: So assuming I have a form on my index.html? Is that what you mean? Thanks.

Comment: @neknekmouh Not a form. An associative array of variables passed to the `products_details.php` via the URL parameters.

Comment: Okay I see, what is that product_big_$_GET['product_id']}.jpg'> for? How can I display the specific image.

Comment: @neknekmouh I added an update to the answer.